# как получить эффект при скролле где элементы двигаются

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

есть div-ы с текстом и изначальном opacity 0.4 и позиционированные на левом краю окна.нужно чтобы при скролле вниз элементы меняли  opacity на 1 и сдвигались с лева на право где то 100 пикселей.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var elem = document.querySelector('.fix');

window.onscroll = function() {
  //Определяем наше текущее место на странице
  var scrolled = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;

  //Задаём значение от куда до куда работают свойства
  if(scrolled < 500){
    
    //Задаём сами свойства
    elem.style.marginLeft = '0';
    elem.style.opacity = '0.4';
  }
  if(scrolled > 500){
    elem.style.marginLeft = '100px';
    elem.style.opacity = '1';
  }         
};
```

```css
body {
  height: 1000px;
}

.fix {
  margin: 0px;
  opacity: 0.4;
  position: fixed;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
 <div class="fix">11111</div>
```

Comment: спасибо и дай бог здоровья